# Bootloader - Display String Runtime Error

Tags: c, linux, inline-assembly, bootloader

I am going to write my first "hello world" bootloader program.I found an article on CodeProject website.Here is link of it.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664165/Writing-a-boot-loader-in-Assembly-and-C-Part
Up-to assembly level programming it was going well, but when I wrote program using c,same as given in this article, I faced a runtime error.
Code written in my `.c` file is as below.

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000,$main\n");

void printstring(const char* pstr)
{
        while(*pstr)
        {
              __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10": :"a"(0x0e00|*pstr),"b"(0x0007));
              ++pstr;
        }
}

void main()
{
        printstring("Akatsuki9");
}
```

I created image file `floppy.img` and checking output using `bochs`.
It was displaying something like this

```
Booting from floppy...
S
```

It should be `Akatsuki9`. I don't know where did I mistake? Can any one help me to find why am I facing this runtime error?

Comment: What ASM instructions did you use when it worked?

Comment: I was displaying character by character and if you want to see code you can find it on given link.But here, now I am trying to use while loop to display String.And may be because of that I am facing this error.But I can't figure it out where and why?

Comment: `__asm__ __volatile__("movb $'H' , %al\n");`
     `__asm__ __volatile__("movb $0x0e, %ah\n");`
     `__asm__ __volatile__("int  $0x10\n");`

Comment: Yes, It's working.That's make me confuse little more.If this logic is working so while loop logic should work.But it isn't.

Comment: I don't believe that specifying the registers in the clobber list like that will cause them to be loaded, it's simply to specify which register to use in the place of %0, %1 etc. Try adding the explicit `movb` opcodes into the inline assembler first.

Comment: hey @slugonamission, 
I already did it by writing code explicitly and it works but I want to write it using while loop.And as you say write it explicitly, but I don't how I do `OR` operation of pointer with register.

Comment: @slugonamission: He's not listing the registers in the "clobber" list.  He's listing them as input parameters, and yes, you can specify values to inputs.  What might be interesting is seeing the asm output from gcc.  If you build your code with -S, what does the output look like?  And what compile switches are you using?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd - specifying "a", "b", "c", "d", "S" or "D" specifies you are passing a value, *and* you would like it to be in the corresponding register (i.e. `eax`, `ebx` etc). http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss6.1

Comment: Make sure you are compiling the correct C code. The 'S' character in the display makes me feel like you were compiling the wrong source code, probably the test2.c in the link, instead of the test4.c example code. You could deliberately bring some syntax to your code and see if the compiling is successful, to double check that this is not the issue.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu, I checked it twice.Did test4.c working on your system?If you tried to run this test4.c & if it worked than please tell me how?

Comment: @Akatsuki, I have tried to answer your question. Please accept it if it does answer your question.

Comment: @Akatsuki: Don't use C. The space (< 512 bytes) is far too limiting, no BIOS functions use C calling conventions, and modern compilers don't support segmentation (even if they do have buggy support for 16-bit code). Instead, use assembly to load more from disk and implement routines to switch between real mode and 32-bit protected mode; then use C for 32-bit protected mode code.

Answer (score 5):

**Brief Answer:** The problem is with *gcc* (in fact, this specific application of generated code) and not with the C program itself. It's hidden in the assembly code.

**Long Answer:** A longer (more elaborate) explanation with specific details of the problem:
(It would be helpful to have the assembly code. It can be obtained using the **-S** switch of *gcc* or use the one that I got from *gcc*; I've attached it at the end). If you don't already know about opcode-prefixing, c-parameter passing in assembly, etc. then have a look at the following background information section. Looking at the assembly source, it's evident that it's 32bit code. *gcc* with '.code16' produces 16bit code for 32bit-mode processor (using operand-size prefixes). When this same exact code is run in real (i.e. 16bit) mode, it is treated as 32bit code. This is not an issue (80386 and later processors can execute it as such, previous processors just ignore the operand-size prefix). The problem occurs because *gcc* calculates offsets based on 32bit-mode of (processor) operation, which is not true (by default) when executing boot-code.

Some background information (experienced assembly language programmers should skip this):
**1. Operand-size prefix:** In x86, prefix bytes (0x66, 0x67, etc.) are used to obtain variants of an instruction. 0x66 is the operand-size prefix to obtain instruction for non-default operand size; *gas* uses this technique to produce code for '.code16'. For example, in real (i.e. 16bit) mode, `89 D8` corresponds to `movw %bx,%ax` while `66 89 D8` corresponds to `movl %ebx,%eax`. This relationship gets reversed in 32bit mode. 
**2. parameter passing in C:** Parameters are passed on stack and accessed through the EBP register. 
**3. Call instruction:** Call is a branching operation with the next instruction's address saved on stack (for resuming). near Call saves only the IP (when in 16bit mode) or EIP ( when in 32bit  mode). far Call saves the CS (code-segment register) along with IP/EIP. 
**4. Push operation:** Saves the value on stack. The size of object is subtracted from ESP.

## Exact problem

We start at the 
`movl    %esp, %ebp` in main:     {{ %ebp is set equal to %esp }} 
`pushl   $.LC0` subtracts 4 from Stack Pointer    {{ .LC0 addresses the char* "Akatsuki9"; it is getting saved on stack (to be accessed by printstring function) }}
`call    printstring` **subtracts 2 from Stack Pointer (16bit Mode; IP is 2bytes)** 
`pushl   %ebp` in printstring: {{ 4 is subtracted from %esp }}
`movl    %esp, %ebp` {{ **%ebp and %esp are currently at 2+4(=6) bytes from the char *pstr** }}
`pushl   %ebx` changes %esp but not %ebp 
`movl    8(%ebp), %edx` {{ **Accessing 'pstr' at %ebp+8 ???** }}

**Accessing 'pstr' at %ebp+8 instead of %ebp+6**  (*gcc* had calculated an offset of 8, assuming 32bit EIP); the program has just obtained an invalid pointer and it's going to cause problem when the program dereferences it later: `movsbl  (%edx), %eax`.

## Fix

As of now I don't know of a good fix for this that will work with *gcc*. For writing boot-sector code, a native 16bit code-generator, I think, is more effective (size-limit & other quirks as explained above). If you insist on using *gcc* which currently only generates code for 32bit mode, the fix would be to avoid passing function parameters. For more information, refer to the *gcc* and *gas* manuals. And please let me know if there is a workaround or some option that works with *gcc*.

#### EDIT

I have found a fix for the program to make it work for the desired purpose while still using *gcc*. Kinda hackish & clearly **not-recommended**. Why post then? Well, sort of proof of concept. Here it is: (just replace your printstring function with this one)

```
void printstring(const char* pstr)
{
  const char *hackPtr = *(const char**)((char *)&pstr-2);
  while(*hackPtr)
  {
    __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10": :"a"(0x0e00|*hackPtr),"b"(0x0007));
    ++hackPtr;
  }
}
```

*I invite @Akatsuki and others (interested) to verify that it works. From my above answer and the added C-pointer arithmetic, you can see why it should.*

#### My Assembly-Source file

```
    .file   "bootl.c"
#APP
    .code16

    jmpl $0x0000,$main

#NO_APP
    .text
    .globl  printstring
    .type   printstring, @function
printstring:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    pushl   %ebx
    .cfi_offset 3, -12
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx
    movl    $7, %ebx
.L2:
    movsbl  (%edx), %eax
    testb   %al, %al
    je  .L6
    orb $14, %ah
#APP
# 8 "bootl.c" 1
    int $0x10
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    incl    %edx
    jmp .L2
.L6:
    popl    %ebx
    .cfi_restore 3
    popl    %ebp
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   printstring, .-printstring
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
    .string "Akatsuki9"
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    pushl   $.LC0
    call    printstring
    popl    %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: ,First of all thanks for your explanation you have given here. But I stuck in C programming. I tried your logic in my file. But still it didn't print string. And I had not tried you assembly code yet.May be your code will work.If you don't mind I will check it & accept your answer.And once again,Thanks Brother  :)

Comment: @Akatsuki, Did you try replacing the `C` `printstring` function with the one I added as edit to my answer. It should work. But if you want to fix the problem in assembly code itself, just try replacing `movl 8(%ebp), %edx` with `movl 6(%ebp), %edx` in the assembly code for `printstring` function.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and found a solution that may work for you. It works on the emulators (I tested on `bochs` and `qemu`), but can't make it work on real hardware.

### Solution

One thing is to use [`gcc-4.9.2`](https://gcc.gnu.org/), and to change the code generation to `.code16gcc`.

Thus, your code becomes:

```
__asm__(".code16gcc\n");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0000,$main\n");

void printstring(const char* pstr)
{
        while(*pstr)
        {
              __asm__ __volatile__("int $0x10": :"a"(0x0e00|*pstr),"b"(0x0007));
              ++pstr;
        }
}

void main()
{
        printstring("Akatsuki9");
}
```

and to compile it use the `-m16` flag on `gcc`, in my case I tried

```
gcc -c -m16 file.c
```

Note that you can change the architecture according to your needs, by setting `-march`. Or if you want to keep the flags of the tutorial

```
gcc -c -g -Os -march=i386 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror -m16 file.c
```

### tl;dr

Set `.code16gcc` instead of `.code16`, and use `-m16` with `gcc-4.9.2`.